# JQuery $.post not working on some PCs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I have a very strange problem with JQuery $.post()
I have implemented it in my new web application and get messed response from QA after testing, some say it is working perfectly and some say it is not working;
It generate no error and no warning,,, but i am very upset i have almost compeleted the application and it is impossible to use some alternative,,, please if some one has any idea then please help me.
Regards

Comment: Have you checked that Javascript is enabled on the PCs where it's not working?

Comment: This question is too vague to provide a useful response.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to write a simple test page that makes only a *$.post* call and print a result (like 'test passed'). This way you can be sure that there is no other problem in your application causing the error. Afterwards you can send this link to the QA and see if the XHR requests are really working (or not).

Comment: thanks for your suggestion after a big research i find that when i passed the url starts with http:// it break exactly at this point on some computer not on all, when i remove it properly send the request,,, but putting http:// is mandatory for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the specify  computer setting, such as different browsers or browser security configuration or others, check then step by step. You should  may the error logs more detail. otherwise you can use HTTP sniffer tools such as firebug, ieinspectoer..